# AS3 hitTestObject to end game

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, flash-cs5

Hello I've tried to create a game , similar to space invaders, and finding it difficult to create a hitTestObject, so if the alienbullet hits mc_gun the player loses a life, and once his lost three lifes the game is over and is taken to a screen where he/she can enter their name to take onto a high score table.

I still have to do the following, but do not know where to start...

Create three lifes for player.
End game when all lifes are gone.
taken to enter name screen
Highscore table.

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my coding in the body of the document...

```
stop();
var score:Number = 0;
var livesLeft:Number = 3;

var lifesArray:Array = new Array();
lifesArray.push(life1);
lifesArray.push(life2);
lifesArray.push(life3);

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, pulse);

function pulse(event:Event):void
{
    checkForHitOnGun();
    checkForHitOnAliens();
    checkForBulletOnBulletHit();
    //checkEndGameCondition 
}

function checkForHitOnGun()
{
    for (var i=0; i<numChildren; i++)
    {
        if (getChildAt(i) is alienbullet)
        {
            var mc_alienbullet:MovieClip = getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;
            for (var j=0; j<numChildren; j++)
            {
                if (getChildAt(j) is gun)
                {
                    var mc_gun:MovieClip = getChildAt(j) as MovieClip;
                    if (mc_alienbullet.hitTestObject(mc_gun))
                    {

                    health -= 10;
                    if (health<1){
                        if(livesLeft<1){
                            gotoAndPlay(2);
                            removeChild(mc_gun);
                            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,pulse);


                        }
                        livesLeft--;
                        lifesArray[livesLeft].visible = false;

                        health=100;
                        if (livesLeft == 0){
                            (endGo);
                            gotoAndPlay(2);
                        }
                    }
                    trace("health =" +health);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


function checkForHitOnAliens()
{
    for (var i=0; i<numChildren; i++)
    {
        if (getChildAt(i) is bullet)
        {
            var mc_bullet:MovieClip = getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;
            for (var j=0; j<numChildren; j++)
            {
                if (getChildAt(j) is alien)
                {
                    var mc_alien:MovieClip = getChildAt(j) as MovieClip;
                    if (mc_bullet.hitTestObject(mc_alien))
                    {
                        var tobeDestroyed:MovieClip;
                        if (mc_alien.x > mc_bullet.x)
                        {
                            tobeDestroyed = mc_alien;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tobeDestroyed = mc_alien;
                        }
                        var bomb_mc:explosion = new explosion();
                        bomb_mc.x = tobeDestroyed.x;
                        bomb_mc.y = tobeDestroyed.y;

                        var addspaceship:alien = new alien();

                        addspaceship.x = 600;
                        addspaceship.y = Math.random()*(stage.stageHeight);

                        tobeDestroyed.destroy();
                        addChild(bomb_mc);
                        addChild(addspaceship);
                        score++;

                        return;
                    }
                }
                tb_score.text = "" + score;
            }
        }
    }
}

function checkForBulletOnBulletHit()
{
    for (var i=0; i<numChildren; i++)
    {
        if (getChildAt(i) is bullet)
        {
            var mc_bullet:MovieClip = getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;
            for (var j=0; j<numChildren; j++)
            {
                if (getChildAt(j) is alienbullet)
                {
                    var mc_alienbullet:MovieClip = getChildAt(j) as MovieClip;
                    if (mc_bullet.hitTestObject(mc_alienbullet))
                    {
                        var tobeDestroyed:MovieClip;
                        if (mc_bullet.x > mc_alienbullet.x)
                        {
                            tobeDestroyed = mc_bullet;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tobeDestroyed = mc_alienbullet;

                        }
                        /*score++;
                        tb_score.text = "" + score;*/
                        var bomb_mc:explosion = new explosion();
                        bomb_mc.x = tobeDestroyed.x;
                        bomb_mc.y = tobeDestroyed.y;

                        tobeDestroyed.destroy();
                        addChild(bomb_mc);
                        /*if (mc_bullet.hitTestObject(mc_alienbullet))
                        {
                        score++;
                        mc_bullet.gotoAndPlay(2);
                        }*/
                        score++;

                        return;
                    }
                    tb_score.text = "" + score;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
//mc_gun would make the bullet fire only if the gun is clicked. 
//the game is to difficult so i changed it to stage. to make the whole stage the fireing area.
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fire);

function fire(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var bulletfire:bullet = new bullet();
    bulletfire.x = mc_gun.x - 20 + mc_gun.width;
    bulletfire.y = mc_gun.y;
    addChild(bulletfire);
}

mc_banner.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGo);

function startGo(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    mc_banner.visible = false;
    mc_instructions.visible = false;
    mc_highscore.visible = false;
    mc_gun.visible = true;
    tb_score.visible = true;
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, pulse);
    var initialspaceship:alien=new alien();

    initialspaceship.x = 600;
    initialspaceship.y=Math.random()*(stage.stageHeight);
    addChild(initialspaceship);

}

function endGo()
{
    mc_gun.visible = false;
    tb_score.visible = false;
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, pulse);
    mc_banner.visible = true;
    livesLeft--;
    lifesArray[livesLeft].visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried? Where are you falling? What went right and what went wrong? Please, be more specific about your problem, as your question is to broad...

Comment: @NemoStein I've got the lifes working were the player gets three lives, however when the lives are all gone, what coding would i apply to end the game and clear all the elements of screen which is then taken to a new screen displaying enter name to add to high score table.

Answer (score 0):

Your `engGo()` function is the one responsible to decrement a life.
This is the best place to check if the player is dead for good (0 lives) and end the game.
As I can understand reading your code, `livesLeft` is where you store the lives of the player.
Just after the `lifesArray[livesLeft].visible = false;` add the following:

```
if (livesLeft <= 0)
{
    defeat();
}
```

Now you must change from GamePlay to HighScore.
If you are working in a frame in Flash Pro, you just need to move to the one with the HighScore

```
function defeat():void
{
    gotoAndStop("HighScore");
}
```

Else (you need to do it all in one frame), you need to clear the stage and add new stuff on it.

```
function defeat():void
{
    // First, remove ALL listeners
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, pulse);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fire);

    // Then, we remove everything
    removeChild(...);

    // Finally, you add the new stuff
    addChild(...);
}
```

If you're going with the second approach, I'd recommend that you decouple your functions and wrap them in classes, so your game logic will be all in one place (in one class), your high score screen will be in another and you can swap them easily.

Comment: I've edited the code to display my lifes, however i think this is incorrect? you said to add the lifes section in endGo how would i do this...? I really appreciate your help

Comment: can you help were i would create the lifes ? i understand the function defeat but cant figure out how to create the lifes

Comment: @DP187, What do you mean by "create the lifes"?

Comment: As in if you look at the coding I've edited it so that function checkForHitOnGun() would result in losing a life when player is hit. however i believe i have done this wrong... how would i give the player three lifes, and once the lifes are over the screen goes to a page were user can input their name which is saved to a highscore table. i understand the coding which you gave me. which would run once the user loses all three lifes... my question simply is how do i code in three lifes and where would i put the coding? 

Thanks DP

Comment: any help tonight would be much appreciated, Please and Thank you

Comment: I am still stuck with this problem... i have a deadline for tonight and any help would be much appreciated

Thanks DP

Comment: You have more than a few unaccepted answers, which can lead people to believe that their time/effort in helping you might not be appreciated.